# Determine if PyObject* is PyLongDoubleScalarObject (numpy)

Tags: c++, python, numpy, boost-python

Given a `PyObject*` in C++ how to determine if it is an instance of `PyLongDoubleScalarObject`?

`PyLongDoubleScalarObject` is the corresponding numpy class to store 128bit floats (`long double`), which is defined in `numpy/arrayscalars.h`.

Using `dynamic_cast` doesn't work as `PyObject*` non-polymorphic. When I look how to do something corresponding to `dynamic_cast` for `PyObject` then I mostly find a hint to use functions such as `PyLong_Check`, but I don't find something like `PyLongDouble_Check`.

Comment: The `PyLongDoubleScalarObject` should, like every non-variable length `PyObject`, include a member called `ob_type`, which is a pointer to an object that represents the type. It should point to the same address for all Python objects of the same type, usually the address of an object named `X_Type` where `X` is the type name. I am unsure what the name of the type object is in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C API equivalent to Python's `isinstance` function is `PyObject_TypeCheck`, so you could do something like:

```
if (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, typeobject)) {
     /* obj matches the given type */
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to check the exact type of the object and not accept subtypes, you can check the type directly:

```
if (Py_TYPE(obj) == typeobject) {
    /* obj is an instance of the given type and not a subclass */
}
```

Note that you need to pass the object representing the type at the Python level rather than the C struct defining the layout of instances.  Looking at the numpy headers, it looks like the type object you're after is probably `&PyLongDoubleArrType_Type`.